# ¿ Cómo borrar un elemento del carrito de compras laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

```
     public function add_compra($id_compras)
     { 
    $Variables = Productos::all();
   $producto=Productos::where('id_productos','=',$id_compras)->get();
   $productos_add=session()->get('productos_add');
   $cont_prod=session()->get('cont_prod',1);
   
   $productos_add[$cont_prod]=[
       'id_producto'=>$producto[0]->id_productos,
       'codigo_producto'=>$producto[0]->codigo,
       'nombre_producto'=>$producto[0]->nombre,
      
   ];
   $cont_prod++;
    session()->put('productos_add',$productos_add);
    session()->put('cont_prod',$cont_prod);
      //dd($productos_add);
     return view('compras.verCarrito',compact('Variables'));
// return back();
    }

public function verCarrito()
{  
    $Variables = Productos::all();
    return view('compras.verCarrito' ,compact('Variables'));
}
public function eliminarelementoCarrito($id)
{
    $cart = Session::get("productos_add");

    foreach (Session::get("productos_add") as $key =>$Productos) { 
        if(Session::get("productos_add['id_producto']")==$id){
    unset($cart['id_producto']);
   session()->forget($cart['id_producto']);
        }
        }
    return view('compras.verCarrito',compact('cart')); 
     }

 array:2 [▼
  1 => array:3 [▼
"id_producto" => 13
"codigo_producto" => "434334"
"nombre_producto" => "nike huarache"
 ]
2 => array:3 [▼
"id_producto" => 12
"codigo_producto" => "7791293012087"
"nombre_producto" => "nike force  1"
 ]
]
```

El tema es que no me genera error, sino que hace el efecto de actualizar, pero no borra el elemento, además utilice forget y tampoco elimina, la ultima parte es donde ago una muestra con dd al carrito para ver su contenido, nose que mas necesitan
add_compra es para añador al carrito lo cual me inserta de maravilla
verCarrito puedo visualizar el carrito
eliminarelementoCarrito pues aca tengo la falla, nose en el foreach por que esta $Productos en ninguna parte del metodo lo señalo

Comment: ¿Para eliminar algo de session no se utiliza el **forget**?  algo asi como `Session::forget($id);`... no veo que lo hagas, tan solo manipulas una variable nueva llamada $cart y la muestras pero sin eliminar nada del session

Comment: Hola, pues utlizo forget, session()->forget($cart['id_producto']); y tampoco elimina, instuyo que el foreach esta mal, que impresion te da a ti con la nueva actualizacion del codigo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sustituye toda la función `eliminarelementoCarrito()` por esta:

```php
public function eliminarelementoCarrito($id)
{
    $cart = Session::get("productos_add");

    foreach (Session::get("productos_add") as $key => $Producto) { 
        if($Producto['id_producto'] == $id){
            unset($cart[$key]);
            session()->forget($key);
        }
    }
    return view('compras.verCarrito',compact('cart')); 
}
```

**Explicación de los cambios**

Recorremos los productos mediante el bucle original que ya tenias, donde despiezabas cada producto en su clave *(=$key)* y su array con los datos *(=$Producto)* pero:

1. En lugar de este condicional:

```
if(Session::get("productos_add['id_producto']")==$id){
```

ponemos este otro:

```
if($Producto['id_producto'] == $id){
```

porque lo que nos interesa es saber, dentro de cada *producto* despiezado, si el valor de la clave `id_producto` coincide con el `id` pasado como parámetro de la funcion a eliminar.

2. En caso afirmativo entramos en el condicional y realizamos las siguientes operaciones:

```
unset($cart[$key]);
```

Esta operación de arriba es para eliminar, mediante la clave que contiene al producto entero (=$key), dicho producto del array `$cart` (que venia a ser una copia del contenido en *session*), que luego utilizarás para la vista, y así evitamos que se muestre el producto eliminado en la vista.

3. Y por último, hacemos esta operación aún dentro del condicional:

```
session()->forget($key);
```

para exactamente lo mismo, pero en *session*.  De este modo, la proxima vez que invoquemos a *session* ese dato ya habrá desaparecido y no se volverá a mostrar.

Comment: Hola buenas, no me funciona, faltará actualizar el carro?

Comment: si funciona, explícamelo porfavor

Comment: Vale, ya he agregado la explicación, cualquier duda me comentas.

Comment: Por cierto, veo que no has aceptado aún ninguna respuesta en tu perfil, y deberias hacerlo cuando las respuestas son válidas para tu pregunta para que no queden pendientes eternamente en el sitio. Aqui te dejo un [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) donde explica cómo aceptarlas, y este otro [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) donde explica el porque es importante hacerlo para la comunidad. (perdón, si que lo hicistes una vez, no la veia)